# Dependencies conflict

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, pubspec.yaml, flutter-pubspec

I'm new to Flutter and encountered this issue while trying to get some pictures from my `pubspec.yaml` file, the latest available version preventing an old version. A solution recommendation will be much appreciated.

#### Result of `flutter pub get`

```
C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub get
Resolving dependencies...
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
Got dependencies!
3 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
```

#### Result of `flutter pub outdated`

```
C:\src\flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat --no-color pub outdated
Showing outdated packages.
[*] indicates versions that are not the latest available.

Package Name  Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest  

direct dependencies: all up-to-date.

dev_dependencies: all up-to-date.
all dependencies are up-to-date.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

#### Result of `flutter pub upgrade`

```
During pub upgrade
Resolving dependencies...
  material_color_utilities 0.5.0 (0.8.0 available)
  meta 1.10.0 (1.11.0 available)
  web 0.3.0 (0.4.0 available)
No dependencies changed.
3 packages have newer versions incompatible with dependency constraints.
Try `flutter pub outdated` for more information.
Process finished with exit code 0
```

**THE PUBSPEC.YAML FILE**

```yaml
name: i_go_rich
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/diamond.png
```

Comment: Please add the code from `pubspec.yaml` file.

Comment: name: i_go_rich
description: "A new Flutter project."
publish_to: 'none'

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: '>=3.2.0 <4.0.0'


dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter



  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.6

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter


  flutter_lints: ^3.0.1

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/diamond.png

Comment: Did you try to run `flutter clean` ?